# Facing issue while using the jira api getting org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character

Tags: java, jira-rest-java-api

When I am using the Jira Api to get an issue, it throws the following exception:

> org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character 169402 of
>   {"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations

....    lot of other information fetched for that particular issue.

I am using `com.atlassian.jira.rest.client-2.0.0-m31.w2`

Below is the code I am using :

```java
JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraURI, username, password); 

IssueRestClient issueClient = client.getIssueClient();

Promise<Issue> issue = issueClient.getIssue(jiraNumber);

keyIssue = issue.get();
```

`jiraURI` is the Jira system our company is using something of the form `https://jiratest.int.kronos.com`

The object issue contains the json exception mentioned above.

Can you please help me out ?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, I had a custom (scripted) field on the issue that was populated with HTML code. It somehow breaks the API... When I removed the custom field, then everything is fine. I'm still figuring out why this custom field breaks the API.